# Continuous file corruptions multiple GIT repositories containing Django Projects

Tags: css, django, git, web, gitlab

I have this very frustrating and weird problem regarding two Django Projects, which are in 2 separate GIT repositories.

Let me define project 1 as **A** and project 2 as **B**.

**A** has a homepage, with a connecting home.css file. I have checked the git repository for the contents of this file, overwriting my local copy, and copy pasted the raw contents of this file to home.css -> the homepage displays fine. Now, whenever I quit the Django processes and the virtual environment associated with it, and commit everything on git, and run the project again, the home.css file is suddenly corrupted. The page now looks like this: 
[image: wrong home page]

If I delete the home.css file from the directory and run the following commands:

```
git fetch origin master
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

The project runs fine again (again the screenshot of the correct markup now):
[image]

The really fun thing is, is that this happens with projects **B** AND **A**
at the same time. So whenever **A** is screwed up, **B** is screwed up. And to add to my confusion: on another computer, with the same repositories, the files are also being changed leading to the corruption of the stylesheet.

What is the culprit? What's going on? The files in the online git repository are correct, because if I paste the raw contents into home.html it works properly again. But after some time, it is messed up. Could it be because of two virtual environments that I'm using for the two projects? Could it be encoding? Could it be a git issue? I'm lost. It's really counterproductive to have this happening every time. There are only 4 files in the two projects that have this error, called home.css (2x) and a base.css and an about.css, so it also shouldn't be name confusion. Moving the repository from Bitbucket to Gitlab also didn't solve the issue. The really strange thing for me is that it happens simultaneously on two machines, so that leads me to think that the issue is not machine dependent. The corruptions always occur on the same lines in the file.

I really hope you guys can help me out.

EDIT:
the corruption occurs always around this line (in the home.css file), but deleting it manually and posting the raw contents from the git version solves the issue...

[image]

Comment: does all this happen with `./manage.py runserver`? how do you manage your staticfiles? what does `git branch -av` and `git status` say when the error occurs?

Comment: This happens with runserver. Default django settings. On the correct branch showing the last commit (the fix commit). Git status is nothing to commit, working directory clean.

Comment: @coderjoe  are projects #1 and #2 in the same repo?  Are you using the same stylesheet?  Did you try to make the changes (that break the css), and open in a different browser to see if it a browser thing?

Comment: They are not in the same repo, separate repos. The stylesheets have the same name but have different content. It is not a browser thing (checked on safari, chrome and firefox), all showing the same output

Answer (score 0):

@coderjoe

Here are some ways to try to troubleshoot (not meant as a solution but couldn't fit in a comment):

The corruptions always occur on the same lines in the file. show the "corruption", and how do you know it occurs on the same lines in the file?

What I propose is this as a first step.

- work on only one computer with one repo
- IF your remote versions are "correct", and I assume your requirements.txt has all of what you want in the venv delete the projects off your computer
- git clone the remote to get a totally fresh install make sure it is working properly.
- do a git diff.  At this point I nothing should have changed
- change the css.  If it fails, do another git diff and check out what lines have changed.  Anything unusual there?
- (read this from the django tutorial on static files)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial06/] check your paths, and follow the instructions on updating the css.

Comment: It is a team project, and the file changes are not in git in any way. Deleting the projects and cloning them again did not solve the issue. The line changes are only the ones I edited. So there is nothing unusual there. The django static files are working properly, and it is on a selective number of files that these errors occur. So that last bullet would not be the issue.